Unable to install kubeadm on centos
Attempting to install kubeadm on my host results in the below error:
[root]# yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package kubeadm-1.30.4-150500.1.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package kubectl-1.30.4-150500.1.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kubelet.x86_64 0:1.30.4-150500.1.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kubernetes-cni >= 1.2.0 for package: kubelet-1.30.4-150500.1.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: socat for package: kubelet-1.30.4-150500.1.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: conntrack for package: kubelet-1.30.4-150500.1.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kubelet.x86_64 0:1.30.4-150500.1.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: conntrack for package: kubelet-1.30.4-150500.1.1.x86_64
---> Package kubernetes-cni.x86_64 0:1.4.0-150500.1.1 will be installed
---> Package socat.x86_64 0:1.7.2.2-5.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: kubelet-1.30.4-150500.1.1.x86_64 (kubernetes)
           Requires: conntrack
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 3 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
ipa-client-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.x86_64 has installed conflicts freeipa-client: ipa-client-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.x86_64
ipa-client-common-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-client-common: ipa-client-common-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.noarch
ipa-common-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-common: ipa-common-4.4.0-12.el7.centos.noarch
[root@master1 yum.repos.d]#


we are also getting some info

There's no supported version of CentOS. You need to upgrade your environment.
